# Middleman use custom helper function inside config.rb file

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have defined a helper function inside the config.rb file. When I use it elsewhere, it works fine. But I have to use that function inside the config.rb as well simultaniously. Unfortunately there is an error:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `slug' for #<Middleman::ConfigContext:0xa137b44> (NoMethodError)
```

Is it nevertheless possible to access a function inside the helpers in config.rb file? Or do I have to declare the function outside globally and then access it from both inside the helper function and somewhere else in the file?

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm running with the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not find a good solution either yet :/  
I just declared the function in the global scope and called it again inside the helper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by requiring my helper **and** including the module like this in config.rb:

```
require 'helpers/slugify_helper'
include SlugifyHelper
```

Then I was able to call my helper method from config.rb like: `slugify(url)`.

FYI: I'm running Middleman `~> 4.2.1`.

Comment: Finally I tested it and it worked fine! Do you know, why `helpers SlugifyHelper` does not for in that case?